# C++ Change variable name inside for

Tags: c++

I have a number of char variables and they are named like tb11, tb12, tb13, tb14, tb21, tb22, tb23, tb24, tb31....
I want to change the number part in my variable names with for loop iterations

```
for(int i = 1; i<=6 ; i++)
{
  for(int j = 1; j<=4 ; j++)
  {
      tb(i)(j).readText; //this is my problem
  }
}
```

How can i change my variable name inside for loop like this?

Comment: You can't change variable names

Answer (score 7):

You can't.  You should use an array like this tb[][] and you can access it like tb[i][j].  Don't name variables tb1, tb2, ...  That's just silly.

Comment: Yeah you are right but i am using nextion hmi with arduino. Nextion hmi is not allowing arrays. So i have use it like this. Then its look i will take all textboxes to an array for use.

Comment: I find it very hard to believe that arrays are not supported.

Comment: https://www.itead.cc/wiki/Nextion_Instruction_Set

Comment: If that's the language you're using why is your question tagged C++?

Comment: It is comminucating with arduino and arduino is using too near a c++ language. I am calling textboxes from hmi to arduino. Finally i am using this code in arduino.

Comment: So you're not using the nextion instruction set here, but arduino's "almost" c++ language, which almost definitely has arrays?